# Remove lines with less than 3 occurrences (by groups)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a table like the one below. I want to keep cases only when the table have 3 or more values related to a person, grouped by role and question (except when the role is Leader).

Example: I would keep all lines about Person A, because there's at least 3 partners answering question 1, question 2 and question 3. In contrast, I need to remove the lines about questions 1 and 2 related to Person B, because just 1 partner answered Q1 and only 2 partners answered Q2. 3 partners answered Q3, so that's ok to keep.

I think I explained pretty badly to be honest, sorry in advance.

| **Person** | **Question** | **Role** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | Question 1 | Leader |
| Person A | Question 2 | Leader |
| Person A | Question 3 | Leader |
| Person A | Question 1 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 1 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 1 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 2 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 2 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 2 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 3 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 3 | Partner |
| Person A | Question 3 | Partner |
| Person B | Question 1 | Leader |
| Person B | Question 2 | Leader |
| Person B | Question 3 | Leader |
| Person B | Question 1 | Partner |
| Person B | Question 2 | Partner |
| Person B | Question 2 | Partner |
| Person B | Question 3 | Partner |
| Person B | Question 3 | Partner |
| Person B | Question 3 | Partner |

Comment: Yes it's quite unclear. Are the duplicates meaningful? Are the questions across different persons linked?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can `groupby` `Person` and `Question` column and keep the group where `Role` except `Leader` count is more than 3.

```py
out = (df.groupby(['Person', 'Question'])
       .filter(lambda g: g['Role'].ne('Leader').sum() >= 3))
```

```
print(out)

      Person    Question     Role
0   Person A  Question 1   Leader
1   Person A  Question 2   Leader
2   Person A  Question 3   Leader
3   Person A  Question 1  Partner
4   Person A  Question 1  Partner
5   Person A  Question 1  Partner
6   Person A  Question 2  Partner
7   Person A  Question 2  Partner
8   Person A  Question 2  Partner
9   Person A  Question 3  Partner
10  Person A  Question 3  Partner
11  Person A  Question 3  Partner
14  Person B  Question 3   Leader
18  Person B  Question 3  Partner
19  Person B  Question 3  Partner
20  Person B  Question 3  Partner
```